# Why is the order of PHP code ignored in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to PHP, and I wanted to create a code where the thumbnail of the newest post and the post title get displayed. Both the title and the image should be inside a `<a href="#">`, so that people can view the article by clicking on the image. But when I run the following PHP code the code gets printed out like this:

```html
<img width="462" height="260" src="http://vocaloid.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/1920x1080_PC_a.jpg" class="attachment-735x260 wp-post-image" alt="1920x1080_PC_a"><a href="http://vocaloid.de/news/test-nr-2/"><h2>HATSUNE MIKU: PROJECT DIVA F EXTEND ANGEKÜNDG</h2></a>
```

Here is the original code I used:

```
<?php
    $args = array('numberposts' => '1' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' . the_post_thumbnail($recent['ID'], array(735,260)); the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>' ); '</a>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: I guess there is a point or comma error... But I am unsure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$args = array('numberposts' => '1' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">';
    the_post_thumbnail($recent['ID'], array(735,260));
    echo the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>' ).'</a>';
}
```

Let me know the output.

Comment: You can give +1 ;) Happy Coding !

Answer (score 0):

Rohil_PHPBeginner's answer is correct, however I don't think it explains why it occurred.

Where you use `the_post_thumbnail()`, it echos the result and does not return it. It is for this reason it appears in the wrong place when you try to concatenate it into a string.

If you would like to get the post thumbnail you can use  `get_the_post_thumbnail()`

Thus using `get_the_post_thumbnail()` you snippet would end up looking like:

```
<?php
    $args = array('numberposts' => '1' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">'
             . get_the_post_thumbnail($recent['ID'], array(735,260))
             . the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>' )
             . '</a>';
    }
?>
```

I hope this gives further clarity.